# Solr: Query and return x number of types

Tags: solr

I have a large index of files.  One of the fields I have is "content_type".  This field stores the basic type for a file (i.e. pdf, image, video, document, spreadsheet, etc).

I'm running a search on files names (my "title" field).  How can I structure the query so that it returns only a certain amount of each type?

For example, say I have 1000 files with the word "work" in the title. I want to search for "work" in the title, but I want 5 results from each "content_type" returned first. (assuming that each specific content_type has 5 or more items).  So on my search results page I can say:

1,000 items were found for "work"

Then I start listing listing the items, 5 for each type.

Can anyone help me build a query that will do this?  I'm pretty new to Solr, but I'm hoping this can be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems basically you want to limit and group the results per content type.

Check out the [Solr field Collapsing and grouping feature](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FieldCollapsing)

This will help you to group the results per content type using group.field=content_type
The number of results in a group can be limited by group.limit=5
For the complete list of options refer to the link above.

And you can use the normal query parameters to search the results i.e. q=work

This feature is only available from the Solr 3.3 build.